# Stripe Subscription : Is it ok to finalize an invoice right away?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm wondering if it's ok to call "finalize" (https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/finalize) on an invoice for a subscription renewal right after it's created (I'd call it in the invoice.created webhook).  I don't need to edit the invoice so I'm thinking it's ok to finalize it right away but I might be missing something.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there won't be any modifications needed to the Invoice when it's a draft then yes, you can manually finalize it as soon as it's been created.